# "All men are mortal, Socrates is a man, therefore, Socrates is mortal" original quote

Tags: history-of-philosophy, syllogism

Where the syllogism "All men are mortal / Socrates is a man / Therefore, Socrates is mortal" first appeared?

Comment: Did you notice that later in the article, making it part of the conclusion, the author uses the expression “identical to Socrates”? I can say that the expression is redundant because “The only thing identical to Socrates is Socrates.” Law of Identity, A is A, Aristotle.

Answer (score 6):

*Comment on similar example.*

The example is not from Aristotle.

Categorical propositions with *singular* terms are used in Medieval logic; see [Peter of Spain](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/peter-spain/)'s [Summulae logicales](https://books.google.it/books?id=eRAuAAAAMAAJ) (XIII century):

> **I,8** Propositio singularis est illa [...], ut "*Sortes currit*" [*Socrates runs*].

Into this textbook we can find many examples of them in the discussion of *loci* and *entimema* [**V,3**], bt it seems to me that there is no occurrence of the specific example of syllogism.

According to: Joseph Maria Bochenski, [A History of Formal Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=QXoIAQAAIAAJ) (1961, or.ed.1956), page 232:

> A first widening of the Aristotelian syllogistic consists in the
> admission of singular terms and premisses. [William of Ockham (c.1287–1347)](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ockham/) already knows of the substitution that was to become classic [[Summa Logicae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_Logic), III 1,3;36rb]:

> > Every man is an animal;

> > Socrates is a man;

> > Therefore, Socrates is an animal.

> Here the minor premiss is singular. But Ockham also allows singular propositions as major premisses.

The earliest occurrence I've found is: [Sextus Empiricus](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/sextus-empiricus/), [Outlines of Pyrrhonism (*Pyrrhōneioi hypotypōseis*)](https://www.hup.harvard.edu/catalog.php?isbn=9780674993013), also translated as: [*Outlines of Scepticism*](https://books.google.it/books?id=mzO77w6KvDgC&pg=PA112), **Book II**, 164 [*Many thanks to* [David Wheeler](https://dwheeler.com/essays/all-men-are-mortal.html)]:

> Socrates is human.

> Everything human is an animal.

> Therefore, Socrates is an animal.

Answer (score 1):

Per [David A. Wheeler](https://dwheeler.com/dwheeler.html)'s article "[The Origin of All Men are Mortal](https://dwheeler.com/essays/all-men-are-mortal.html)" (which elsewhere cites this page!)

> The earliest document I can find with this specific example is from 1843, specifically A System of logic: Ratiocinative and Inductive, Presenting a Connected View of the Principles of Evidence and the Methods of Scientific Investigation by John Stuart Mill, 1843, Book II Chapter 3 page 245.

One can indeed see the quote

```
2. It must be granted that in every syllogism, considered as an argument
to prove the conclusion, there is a petitio principii. When we say,

All men are mortal
Socrates is a man
  therefore
Socrates is mortal ;

it is unanswerably urged by the adversaries of the syllogistic theory,
that the proposition, Socrates is mortal, is presupposed in the more
general assumption, All men are mortal:
```

in the [Internet Archive's copy](https://archive.org/details/systemoflogicrat01millrich/page/245/mode/1up) of Mill's [System of Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_System_of_Logic).