# Predication for Aristotle

Tags: aristotle, predicate-logic

According to Aristotle’s predication, in saying “Socrates is a philosopher” would the philosopher be a predication? If so, would referring to a philosopher alone (for example “the philosopher is wise”) still imply that the philosopher is a predication of a human?

Comment: Even though we probably mean “every philosopher is wise” since a philosopher must be a human wouldn’t it also be true that the term philosopher itself predicates humans?

Comment: Yes; "every philosopher is wise" is correct (and presumably true) and also "every human is a philosopher" is correct (and clearly false).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: yes the predications follow through, he discusses this in his Organon for example predicates of a genra apply the individuals of the species with in the genra.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "philosopher" is a predicate that applies to humans. When we say "the philosopher is wise” in English we mean "every philosopher is wise" (**A** form: "Every **S** is **P**").

In [traditional syllogism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/#PreStrAss) *terms* are always universals and the basic form "Every
**S** is **P**" means "**P** is affirmed of all of **S**" expresses the subsumption of an universal into a "greater" (more general) one.

In the original Aristotelian formulation, [individual, like Socrates, are not considered as terms](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/34461/all-men-are-mortal-socrates-is-a-man-therefore-socrates-is-mortal-original).